# Error while installing Nitrogen

Tags: erlang, installation, nitrogen

Thought I'd explore Nitrogen. Following install instructions outlined in http://nitrogenproject.com/doc/tutorial.html, I pulled source from GitHub, executed second step, make rel_inets, and hit a wall. Here is what the system told me:

```
nitrogen$ make rel_inets
...
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen'
Running Erlang
Generating "reltool.config" with merged overlays
...Loading base file: "reltool_base.config"
...Merging Overlay from "reltool_inets.config"
...Writing "reltool.config"
...SUCCESS
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen'
Running Erlang
==> rel (generate)
ERROR: generate failed while processing /home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen/rel: {'EXIT',      {{badmatch,{error,"Illegal library \"/home/lloyd/Programming/Erlang/zippity/apps\": no such file or directory"}},
```

Turns out that /home/lloyd/Programming/Erlang/zippity/apps was deleted long ago; e.g. it's not in my directory tree.

Can any kind wizards tell me why in the world would make dredge up this ancient history? And... what can I do about it?

Many thanks,

LRP

As requested, I've edited line 231 of Makefile. Here's output of make rel_inets:

```
lloyd@Reliance:~/Erl/nitrogen$ make rel_inets
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen'
./rebar get-deps
Running Erlang
==> rel (get-deps)
==> nitrogen (get-deps)
./rebar compile
Running Erlang
==> rel (compile)
==> nitrogen (compile)
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen'
Running Erlang
Generating "reltool.config" with merged overlays
...Loading base file: "reltool_base.config"
...Merging Overlay from "reltool_inets.config"
...Writing "reltool.config"
...SUCCESS
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen'
Running Erlang
DEBUG: Consult config file "/home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen/rel/rebar.config"
DEBUG: Rebar location: "/home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen/rel/rebar"
DEBUG: is_rel_dir(/home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen/rel) -> {true,
                                                    "/home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen/rel/reltool.config"}
DEBUG: Available deps: []
DEBUG: Missing deps  : []
DEBUG: Predirs: []
==> rel (generate)
DEBUG: Consult config file "/home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen/rel/reltool.config"
DEBUG: vcs_vsn: Unknown VCS atom in vsn field: "2.2.2"
DEBUG: vcs_vsn: Unknown VCS atom in vsn field: []
ERROR: generate failed while processing /home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen/rel: {'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,"Illegal library \"/home/lloyd/Programming/Erlang/zippity/apps\": no such file or directory"}},
         [{rebar_reltool,generate,2,[]},
          {rebar_core,run_modules,4,[]},
          {rebar_core,execute,5,[]},
          {rebar_core,process_dir1,6,[]},
          {rebar_core,process_commands,2,[]},
          {rebar,main,1,[]},
          {escript,run,2,[{file,"escript.erl"},{line,747}]},
          {escript,start,1,[{file,"escript.erl"},{line,277}]}]}}
make[2]: *** [generate] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen'
make[1]: *** [rel] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/lloyd/Erl/nitrogen'
make: *** [rel_inets] Error 2
```

Comment: Hi Lloyd. Could you modify the Makefile on line 231:  `@(cd rel; ./rebar generate)` to add `-vvv` switches such that it reads `@(cd rel; ./rebar -vvv generate)`. Then run `make rel_inets` and post the results?  That might give us *some* insight into why erlang is loading a non-existent directory.

Comment: You've got some junk in your environment. Run `printenv | grep zippity` and see what turns up.

Comment: Thanks for posting the update, Lloyd. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to shed any new light. But @NathanielWaisbrot's recommendation is solid. Further, it's possible, based on your recent question on erlang-questions that something is hosed up with your erlang installation, and the recommendations to do a complete wipe and reinstallation of your erlang installation.

Comment: Big thanks guys. Evidently I had set ERL_LIBS sometime back not fully understanding the implications. The ERL_LIBS value was orphaned when I deleted the library directory. So, unset ERL_LIBS did the trick. Nitrogen is now installed.

Comment: @LloydR.Prentice you can add your comment as an answer to this question and mark it accepted, to make it clear that it's a solved problem.

Comment: Big thanks guys. Evidently I had set ERL_LIBS sometime back not fully understanding the implications. The ERL_LIBS value was orphaned when I deleted the library directory. So, unset ERL_LIBS did the trick. Nitrogen is now installed.

Comment: Big thanks guys. Evidently I had set ERL_LIBS sometime back not fully understanding the implications. The ERL_LIBS value was orphaned when I deleted the library directory. So, unset ERL_LIBS did the trick. Nitrogen is now installed. LRP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks guys. Evidently I had set ERL_LIBS sometime back not fully understanding the implications. The ERL_LIBS value was orphaned when I deleted the library directory. So, unset ERL_LIBS did the trick. Nitrogen is now installed.

Re hosed Erlang installation: thanks to tip from Bob Ippolito, I purged Erlang from my system, installed the Erlang dependencies, then reinstalled Erlang via kerl. Rebar now compiles. n2o is still not cooperating--- stalls during compilation after many warnings. But I'll work on that today.

Thanks again,

LRP